# MERN stack server routes not accessible on production

Tags: server, mern

I am building a mern stack app.

It works in development but in production it does not fetch data from server.

Possibly server is not running or I dont know for sure.

Github repo: [Link](https://github.com/nkp1111/mern-stack-app)

Live server running on Vercel: [Link](https://mern-stack-kvapgozok-nkp1111.vercel.app/)

I just want to make sure that a `/home` request to server to show the message,

but it is showing the error 404 not found.

I tried to follow tutorial on mongodb website.